# Show that $u_n$ > $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $(u_n)$ defined by $u_0$>$\sqrt{3}$ , $u_{n+1}$= $\frac 1{2} (u_n + \frac 3{u_n}$) for every n $\in \mathbb N$

Show that $u_n$ > $\sqrt{3}$ for every n $\in \mathbb N$

Comment: AM/GM${}{}{}{}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By AM-GM we get $$\frac{1}{2}(u_n+\frac{3}{u_n})\geq \sqrt{3}$$
We have used that  $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $$a,b\geq 0$$

Comment: My answer was: $u_0$>$\sqrt{3}$ . Assume $u_n$>$\sqrt{3}$ for all n $\in \mathbb N$. Prove $u_{n+1}$>$\sqrt{3}$ for all n $\in \mathbb N$. We get $\frac 3{2}(\sqrt{3})$ $\geq$ $\sqrt{3}$